# Should I trim this small peach tree shoot?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees

I grew this peach tree from a pit from a peach tree that grew in in my yard which grew the most delicious peaches. That was in Seattle 2 years ago but now I live in Colorado and I'd like to plant it in the ground eventually. The leaves are starting to come back after the winter.

I trimmed the tips off the branches because they were dried and dead looking after the winter (maybe 1-2 inches depending on the branch). I was watering the plant in this pot during the winter.

My question is about this little shoot coming off the bottom. Should I cut it completely off? Should I let it grow? It is growing much faster than the rest of the leaves. Is it pulling energy away from the rest of the tree? Is it a problem that it is coming out of the base?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that 'shoot' isn't a separate weed - the leaves appear to have toothed edges, unlike peach leaves. Also, because you grew the plant from a peach pit, it doesn't have a root stock to produce suckers with, so even if its not a weed, I'm not at all sure it needs cutting back. Any new shoots will be coming from the peach roots, not rootstock, but check its not just a weed first.

Comment: @Bamboo I'm pretty sure those are what the leaves looked like on the fully mature peach tree, too. I'll have to see if I have any old pictures when I get home.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should trim them. It is frequent to have such shots on fruit plants (or in general plants which are planted or cut). See also [Epicormic shoot in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicormic_shoot)

Note: plants grow from a fruit could be very different than the mother plant. Better way to have identical fruits, is to graft some branches of mother to a new tree.

Comment: Thank you. I'll clip it tonight. If I still had access to the original tree could I graft it to this plant grown from one of the mother's pits? Or does the grafting need to be unrelated trees?

Comment: Any tree, also related. Sometime some strong tree are preferred (for root). But maybe this tree produce better fruits than the mother. Bamboo or stormy could correct me, but I think you can also put a branch on ground and it will put roots and grow back. OTOH peaches are hard to create new gems.

Comment: What is a gem? You think it's even worth planting in the ground without a graft?

Comment: @Brad A gem is a peach tree that grows good peaches.

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ ...I thought there might be more meaning to it

Comment: @Brad Some peach trees taste horrible, so when you get a good one, it's really a gem. Though I could be wrong and there is a deeper meaning to it.

Comment: Yeah. I was meaning "gemma" (or bud). I have various peach trees grown from pits. Most are very tasty, but they ripen at the same time and they overripe very quickly. In any case I find peach trees "modest" most of the year (so not very noticeable), but in late winter they bloom nicely.